# False positive "Missing include" xslt error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xslt

I have an xslt file in my eclipse project.
The xslt is run using a custom processor, which contains some xslt files as an in-jar resource. The xslt linter does not see those resources, and signals an error.

The offending line in the xslt code:

```
<xsl:include href="xslt/functions.xslt"/>
```

The error message:

```
Missing include: xslt/functions.xslt
```

I guess that the xslt path for the linter is somehow configureable, but cannot find where and how.

Where and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the XML-Catalog-function "Rewrite Entry" and the imports having a prefix which identifies the folder you want to take the import from.

**Window > Preferences : XML > XML Catalog > Rewrite Entry**

You have to provide a URI key type and the prefix of the href-value.
Rewrite it with a "file://xxxx" value and the import gets resolved.

Example:

```
<xsl:include href="imp://xslt/functions.xslt"/>
```

catalog-rewrite-entry for eclipse

```
Entry element:      Rewrite
Start string:       imp://
Rewrite prefix: file:///home/xxx/project/importfolder
Key type:           URI
```

Answer (score 2):

If using the Eclipse XSL Editor (there are also other XSLT editors for Eclipse):

***Window > Preferences: XML > XSL > Validation***

[or on project level:](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/topic/org.eclipse.wst.xsl.doc/html/preferences/validation.html)

***Project > Properties: Validation > XSLT Validation***

Comment: Thank you. I could turn off the error message, but could not configure the include path. Any idea on that?

Comment: @ÁrpádMagosányi Unfortunately, it seems that an include path cannot be configured: include statements are always resolved relative to the file that contains the include statement. See [Eclipse bug 258202](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=258202) for details.